# Adding columns of two relations in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, postgresql-9.1

I have two relations such as relation1 and relation2. relation1 has columns of A,B,C and relation2 has columns of D,E,F.

I want to add A of relation1 with D of relation2 where C = F. For the C values which do not exist in relation2 must appear and F values which do not appear in relation1 also must appear How to do this postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [**`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) to include rows from either side without a matching row on the other side:

```
SELECT COALESCE(r1.a, 0) + COALESCE(r2.d, 0) AS a_d
FROM   relation1      r1
FULL   JOIN relation2 r2 ON r1.c = r2.f
```

Also use [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to catch `NULL` values substituted for missing columns.