# Postgresql relations joining

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have two relations relation1 and relation2 where relation1 has columns A,B,C and relation2 has columns D,E,F. For a query I am doing a full join on relation1 and relation2 on C=F.

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F 
  FROM relation1 r1 FULL JOIN relation r2 
    ON r1.C=r2.F
```

So when C=F, result contains

```
A,B,C,D,E,F values
```

when C is not in F result contains

```
A,B,C, null,null,null
```

when F is not in C result contains

```
null,null,null,D,E,F
```

This is what i expect. Now i want to do C,F to be identified by the same name (M) in results. So when C=F, result contains

```
A,B,M,D,E values
```

when C is not in F result contains

```
A,B,M, null,null,null
```

when F is not in C result contains

```
null,null,null,D,E,M
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT A, B, D, E, COALESCE(C, F) M 
  FROM relation1 r1 FULL JOIN relation2 r2 
    ON r1.C = r2.F
```

Assuming relation1:

```
|  A |  B | C |
---------------
| a1 | b1 | 1 |
| a2 | b2 | 2 |
```

and relation2:

```
|  D |  E | F |
---------------
| d1 | e1 | 1 |
| d3 | e3 | 3 |
```

Output will be

```
|      A |      B |      D |      E | M |
-----------------------------------------
|     a1 |     b1 |     d1 |     e1 | 1 |
|     a2 |     b2 | (null) | (null) | 2 |
| (null) | (null) |     d3 |     e3 | 3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/93434/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias i.e C as M and F as M in your query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A,B,
  case when C is not null then M end,
  D,E,
  case when F is not null then M end
FROM relation1 r1 
  FULL JOIN relation r2 
ON r1.C=r2.F
```

unless M is just an alias then

```
SELECT A,B,C as M, D,E, F as M
FROM relation1 r1 
  FULL JOIN relation r2 
ON r1.C=r2.F
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *no way* to have `M` (as name) in the `SELECT` list twice. Output column names have to be unique.

Generally I would prefer [@peterm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17738649/939860) with `COALESCE()` ([like I answered to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729837/adding-columns-of-two-relations-in-postgresql)).
Here is another way to achieve the same with subqueries and the [`USING` clause for the `JOIN` condition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

```
SELECT A, B, D, E, M 
FROM      (SELECT A, B, C AS M FROM relation1) r1
FULL JOIN (SELECT D, E, F AS M FROM relation2) r2 USING (M)
```